# How to Make a Programmable Tile View (Like the App Store Has)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm building an app, and I want the main view to be "tile" based, kind of like how the App Store looks:
[image: App Store]

In other words, I'd like to be able to add rounded "tiles" (like the get fit, now trending) to my view with certain information- a method that adds tiles in certain scenarios, with certain information. I'd also like the view to be scrollable, and the tiles to expand and reveal more information when clicked.

I have no idea how to start this, so I'm sorry for the vagueness, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone looking to make a UI like the App Store's today page will find what they want in the Cocoapod called "Cards."